# Why is there no Cookies Consent API in browsers?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

Over the last years it is a mainstream topic to give users more control over data they expose to websites, with such options often being incorporated in browsers themselves.

Yet with cookies popups being a sadistic way to cripple user experience, encouraged by hypocritic buerocrats to "protect" poor users from stealing their info, it is still a wonder to me - why is there no such thing as Cookie "Consent" settings, that could be once set by a user and then used by sites to automatically know what cookie types they can save?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the fact that there is no ***standard*** for types of cookies. Most sites try to categorize the types of data they collect, but ultimately until a universal standard is established (for cookies, data categorization, and data collection) it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Well, it is not uncommon for browser vendors to add some non-standard functionality and make it de-facto standard in case of urgent need. And for sites which want to improve their user experience it will make perfect sense to use "nonstandard" google standard.

Comment: "*improve their user experience*" and "*nonstandard*" are far from each other in web development. A big issue with browsers in the past was always that each seemed to implement their own features (*or versions of a feature*), forcing developers to do silly things like display messages like "*this site works best in BrowserXYZ*", or code various levels of compatibility. Even when a browser does push forward an idea as the standard, it takes usually takes years before being accepted as a standard, or implemented across other browsers.

Comment: *For the record* I'm not saying browsers shouldn't have an API available to get things like cookie preferences. I'm just saying the things that need to be in place for that to happen are not there, and it will likely be years before we see it (if at all). The cookie consent laws are not universal or global, and so a standard or API for that would only be relevant to certain countries/regions currently.

Comment: @EssXTee And yet some standards were created by separate members, like canvas by safari for example. Or look how firefox emulates chrome extension api for compatibility and it doesn't cause any catastrophy to the world. Regarding law not being universal - I think any decent regulation will agree that a website using options provided by browser is completely legal way to avoid unnecessary clutter, and if you start with a simple option - "agree with all cookies" / "decide in popups" which is already useful for most of the users it is guaranteed to be compatible with any cookie type schema.

Comment: Also I don't understand how having a feature that can potentially not work across the browsers is worse than not having it at all.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. Firstly, separate browsers creating their own non-standard features is, and has always been a thing. However, today most browsers more closely follow the standards. Back when this was not true, it create several issues for both developers and users. I did mention that browsers have pushed forward ideas that were non-standard at the time, but became standard. And again, when a browser does this it typically takes years before it becomes adopted as standard. So to to answer the original "***Why***", because no browser is currently pushing it as a standard.

Comment: As to "*how having a feature that can potentially not work across the browsers is worse than not having it at all*", just look at the web before most browsers followed standards. Or look at IE. It had a ton of IE only functions and features that on the surface seemed useful and cool, however it created a bad environment for developers and users alike. Either you use a specific browser for a site or you miss out on features. We already lived in a world where this was true and we got away from it because it in fact was not that great.

Comment: Right now you can find a recent api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) which has a nonstandard chrome function. And my original "Why" was more about standard in general sense, so it is exactly "why no browser is currently pushing it as a standard".
Now, talking about IE, do you seriously believe not having this feature in some browser will break user experience there? If you see the api is not there - just show the popup.
This is not a feature that can possibly create any fragmentation, and it seems to be quite obvious to me.

Comment: You should rephrase your original question then, as it would be misleading for those searching. It seems like you had an answer, you were just more interested in why it isn't being pushed as a standard. As for IE, I am citing history on this. This isn't just my opinion, this is literally what happened in the world of web development. "*Just show the popup*" goes straight back to what I've been trying to say. You either force a bad experience on the user (by telling them which browser to use), or you force a bad experience on the developers (for having to duplicate code for multiple browsers).

Comment: Didn't know it would be not obvious that "popup", a word used multiple times here, means cookie popup, not popup telling the user which browser to use. 
A few lines of code to add new api = code duplication, lmao :)
This is top level trolling.

Answer (score 1):

Because rejection can be automated in this case.
Notice, almost every cookie consent menu is built in such a way that sooner or later you get tired of clicking 100500 toggles just to read half of an article. So you **will** be clicking that highlighted green "Agree" button at some point.

To make this API happen, specification must be created and supported by W3C. Just look at the [members](https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Member/List). Many of these companies make money from cookies, so they will not allow them to be rejected automatically.

Comment: Full cookie rejection is already available in browser settings. The new api would be rather about you accepting some or all cookies, and if a website wants to store more - they are fine to show a popup.
Regarding specifications - I think it would be pretty much legal to use api provided by a browser even if it's not a w3c standard.

Comment: And, considering this is a feature that most sites would want to use and therefore make interface sane for people allowing all cookies, it would quickly become de facto standard without any need for lengthy official processes.